# Azure Front Door - Routing Redirect returns 405 Method Not Allowed, but only when going through the Front Door

Tags: azure-front-door

Attempting the following routing with our Azure Front Door:

Assume the Front Door URL is https://foo.azurefd.net, and the backend pool consists of an Azure Web App with URL https://foowebapp.azurewebsites.net.

I have created a routing rule as follows:

User passes `POST:` https://foo.azurefd.net/api/token/12345

I want that to get directed to `POST:` https://foowebapp.azurewebsites.net/api/token

I created the rule using Redirect route type.  The problem is I get a 405 Method Not Allowed when passing this via the Front Door.  If I pass directly to the https://foowebapp.azurewebsites.net/api/token endpoint, I get the expected response.

Why is this happening, and is there another setting in Front Door I need to tweak?

**EDIT:** I can see now in analyzing the traffic that Front Door is changing the method from `POST` to `GET` during the redirect.  This is why I'm getting the 405 Method Not Allowed error.  But I don't understand why Front Door would change it from a `POST` to `GET`.  Everything is set to `HTTPS` only.  I have raised this with Azure support but not sure I expect much assistance from them.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.  By default, Front Door's redirect is set to type 302 (Found).  This kind of redirect will always change any non-GET method to a `GET`.  Using either 307 (Temporary Redirect) or 308 (Permanent Redirect) will allow the call to be passed without change the method.

Comment: + it only works if Redirect protocol is HTTPS only